# How to push data from promise to an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch

I want to push data from promise to array (coursesArray) and then use the array values else where. I am using [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) library to query the API. Currently when i log array inside the promise, it has values(coursesOne) however when i log the array outside the promise, it is empty(coursesTwo). How do i go about implementing the ideal solution so that coursesArray is filled with data when `getCoursesForSitemap()` executes

Here is what i have implemented so far

```
const coursesArray = [];

const getCoursesForSitemap = () => {
  fetch(coursesUrl)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      json.courses.results.map(course => {
        return coursesArray.push(course.slug);
      });
      console.log('coursesOne', coursesArray);
    })

    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
getCoursesForSitemap();
console.log('coursesTwo', coursesArray);
```

Comment: Your log outside runs BEFORE the fetch completes.

Comment: You need to keep chaining anything that needs to wait for completion with `.then` or `await`.

Answer (score 1):

Refactoring your code to use `async`/`await`, and not making it mutate the out-of-closure/global variable, this should work for you.

```js
const getCoursesForSitemap = async () => {
  const result = await fetch(coursesUrl);
  const json = await result.json();
  return json.courses.results.map(course => course.slug);
};
const coursesArray = await getCoursesForSitemap();
console.log('coursesTwo', coursesArray);
```

In case your environment doesn't support *top-level async/await*, you'll need to execute the async code in e.g. an IIFE:

```
(async function() {
  const coursesArray = await getCoursesForSitemap();
  console.log('coursesTwo', coursesArray);
}());
```

(That function will also return a promise you can `.then()` or `await` on...)

Comment: I would like to know what's the benefit of using `async` / `await` over `then` and promise ?

Comment: Am getting this error  `Can not use keyword'await' outside an async function`

Comment: @Nicolas Clearer, flatter code with less indentation. Async/await is (mostly) just syntax sugar for promise management anyway.

Comment: @freetyy Ah, yeah, you are running in an environment that doesn't support top-level async/await. I'll augment the answer.

Comment: How do i access the values that the async code returns for example if i want to assign the values you are logging(coursesTwo) to some other array. Currently when i assign a variable to the IIFE above and i try to log the variable it shows `Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: It's a promise – You will have to `await` for the result, or apply `.then()` on it.

Comment: Can you demonstrate how I can achieve that? I am interested in what the promise returns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201850/discussion-between-freetyy-and-akx).

Comment: I can link you the MDN tutorial on async/await – you'll find it uses `fetch()`, like you do. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to log the values before they are resolved from your promise. That's why it's not working. You need to wait for the Promise to be resolve before trying to show them.

You also need to return the promise .

```
const coursesArray = [];

const getCoursesForSitemap = () => {
  return fetch(coursesUrl)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      json.courses.results.forEach(course => {
        return coursesArray.push(course.slug);
      });
      console.log('coursesOne', coursesArray);
    })

    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
getCoursesForSitemap().then(() => {
    console.log('coursesTwo', coursesArray);
});
```

I've also changed the `map` function you use for a `forEach` since you don't need to change the value of the `json.courses.results` array.